# Azure SQL Database scale

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

The Azure SQL Database pricing & sizing page is very vague when it comes to providing the capacity threshold of their service tiers.  For example, their tiers are mostly broken down into Basic, Standard, and Premium.  Each tier is given a generic low, moderate and high workloads distinction.

My question is, what is their interpretation of low, moderate and high?  What is the order of magnitude that we should expect that each tier is capable of.

For high, do they mean 1K concurrent requests? 10K concurrent requests? 100K concurrent requests?

Comment: I do not see those low, moderate and high categories on the documentation. The following documentation for the each service tier establish some performance levels. For example, for Standard Tiers you can see performance levels from S0 to S12. Maybe this documentation answers your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits

Answer (score 1):

I think the TL;DR answer to what you're looking for is this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits.

Basic, Standard, and Premium are the service tiers. Once you go within a service tier you can configure a maximum [DTU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-what-is-a-dtu) and data size known as a performance level. The capacities available depends on the tier and performance level selected.

- Basic is pretty slow, intended for a playground.
- Standard is suitable for many production environments.
- Premium is for databases with a heavy IO workload.
- Premium RS (preview) is similar to premium except the backup intervals are longer (every 5 min instead of near real time).

There are also new vCore options that are also in preview giving you more control over how many cores are assigned to your workloads.

Once you choose a service tier you can determine the scale, so S0 currently allows for 10DTU's, while S12 allows for 3,000. The [maximum concurrent sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits) depends on the tier you buy.